# Аналог функции insert (строки)

Tags: delphi, строки, функции

Здравствуйте.

Помнится, в **Delphi** была функция (типа **insert**), которая позволяла бы вставлять определенный символ в целую строку через определенное количество символов.

Или я что-то путаю, искал, но не нашел.

Например:

Вставить запятую через каждые **3** символа, в строку **128883684596**,
результат : **128,883,684,596**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert и есть: [help](http://www.delphibasics.ru/Insert.php).

Через определенное кол-во не было, но пишется за 5 мин. на основе этой.

Ну или если разрядность более-менее известна, можно сделать так:

```
S:='128883684596';
ff:=StrToInt64(S);
Result:=FormatFloat('#,###,###.###', ff);
```

Если вместо запятых будут точки, можно настроить, передав третий параметр TFormatSettings.

Comment: Как раз то, что нужно :-)